# Вывести простые числа циклом while

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, выполнить задание (если можно, то с подробными комментариями):

С помощью цикла while вывести все простые числа в промежутке от 0 до 100.

Comment: Могу помочь в понимании смысла слова "Помогите" и его отличия от слова "Сделайте мне".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];
var i = 0;
while (i < a.length) {
  console.log(a[i++]);
}
```